# Difference between Subversion's checkin and import commands?

Tags: svn

What's the difference between `svn checkin` and `svn import`?

It seems both commands can be used to add new entries to the repository, so what's the difference?

Answer (score 7):

Import puts an *unversioned* file or tree into the repository.

Commit puts *changes* from your working copy into the repository.

There is no svn checkin.

Answer (score 2):

I've always thought it to be that 'add' adds new files within an existing repository and puts them under version control, whereas import adds new files but leaves the local copy outside of version control. Add also requires a working repository, whereas import can be used to "seed" a newly created repo.

Edit... the commit then "checks in" the newly added files (akin to an import, but added to the current working repository). Also handles changes to existing (non added) files.